# error: could not convert while compile/Build in QNX with C++ code. Cannot initialize the char file name

Tags: c++11, qnx, momentics, blackberry-qnx

I have the table like this (CONFIG_TABLE) I am trying to initialize the char type using the map.  But unable to build this in QNX : `

```
            #define FILEPATH_SIZE 256
            #define CONFIG_TABLE \
            {\
            {   FIRSTSOUND, {{"./resources/1A.wave"}}} \
            };

            struct ConfigStructure
            {  
            char filePath[FILEPATH_SIZE];  
            };
            static std::map<Uint16, ConfigStructure> myMap = CONFIG_TABLE
```

error: could not convert '{{24576, {"./resources/1A.wave"}}}'   from '' to 'std::__1::map<short unsigned int, himeMgrConfigSt_t>'  };
How to solve the error?
is there any other wave to read it? how to initialize the char path here?

Comment: `CONFIG_TABLE` macro expands to a single opening brace `{`. Did you mean it this way? It looks like the code is missing a few backslashes for line splicing.

Comment: Its not the problem with '\' .  Qnx momentics is not considering the char filePath = "./resource/1A.wave/";
but its working for char filePath = 'a'; for single character.

Comment: Must be something specific to a particular compiler you use. It [works here](https://godbolt.org/z/83Poxrx9z)